Valid Logistic Analysis for Physicists?
I am a physicist in the process of writing a paper concerning the results of a Monte Carlo engine calculating the amount of radiation hitting an target in a radiation field.
Interestingly, while the results are usually accurate, there are some cases where the results are wildly off. As far as we can tell, there isn't an exact parameter set that causes the error, but some parameter sets make it more likely  --- for example, setting the calculation grid size to be coarser causes these errors to be more likely, but it doesn't happen all the time, and it can happen even with fine calculation mesh sizes.
I now have about 20,000 datapoints from various calculations. For each calculation, I have recorded the value of about 15 different input parameters. I have a slight idea which ones are relevant to the output variable, which is the difference in calculated radiation dose between this calculation and a base case known to be correct for the geometry, but many I am unsure of how they might affect the output variable. I know many of my variables are correlated. I would bet some of my variables are multicollinear.
The end goal of this project is to give rough rules of thumb for the use of these calculations in the field of radiation therapy - that is, so that someone planning to set up radiation therapy could follow some rule like "when the target is this big, or this close to this other thing, then you have to set parameter Y like so to reduce the probability of miscalculation".
To get these, I am trying to create a logistic regression model from the input parameters, so that I can say something like "the odds of a miscalculation are less than X when using the parameter set Y, Z, W."
I don't know the best way to go about this. Currently, I am trying to remove multicollinearity by iteratively calculating VIF, then removing the explanatory variable with the highest VIF, repeating, then, once all variables have VIF under 10, running BIC on all remaining combinations of variables to find the most parsimonious set, then creating my rules of thumb by creating a logistic model (scaled and centered data of course) using that set, then inspecting what regions of parameter space have the lowest probabilities according to my logistic model.
However, this idea I have just cobbled together from various CrossValidated posts and reading snippets from textbooks. Really, I don't know what the best method would be moving forward.
What methods would be the most errorproof to a physicist who doesn't really know that much about statistics? What is the correct way to obtain the end-result (rules of thumb) that I am after?
I did read the post here which is related but did not explicitly give a direction to head in. I understand that the idea of a "best way to do statistical analysis" is going to be extremely controversial, but I'm mainly looking for critiques on my current method, suggestions for rather errorproof methods for someone whose specialties lie outside statistics, and further reading.

Welcome to CV, Grim.  Your objective of obtaining "rough rules of thumb" would seem to lead directly to a regression tree or a random forest, because those procedures can yield exactly that and in a potentially nonlinear way that is relatively immune to complications of multicollinearity.  Have you considered such an approach?
